# How to add 1 for two's complement when you have a 1 in the first bit?

Tags: binary

The binary number I was given is 1100101111001000 (16 bits). I understand that this is negative, so, therefore, I have to find the bit representation for the positive number (0100101111001000 - 16 bit) and then flip the bits (101101000110111) and then add one. This is where I am stuck. I know that if the first bit were to be 0, then I would just change it to 1, so does the first bit just become 0 in this case?

Comment: If you're stuck you've got C code you should be including in your question that demonstrates *how* you're stuck. Please edit and include that.

Comment: @tadman There is no C code, just working with binary code. Edited my tag.

Comment: You'll need to come up with something, anything, to show you're invested in solving the problem.

Comment: You've answered your own question -- to negate a two's complement number, you invert all the bits and add 1.  That's it.